# how to use range value search in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am stuck on range search query. Please see this below examples :

```
SELECT * FROM product where status='A' and subcat_id=5 AND product.price < 50 AND  product.price BETWEEN 50 AND 100 AND category = "male"
```

In above example , it does not returns records below 50 yet they are in database.

If I try as in second example below :

```
SELECT * FROM product where status='A' and subcat_id=5 AND product.price < 50 OR  product.price BETWEEN 50 AND 100 AND category = "male"
```

It returns all records which not under male category but less then 50

Finally I want to get records which are in range less then 50 or between 50 to 100 but only for male category.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Try putting brackets around the `AND` clauses before and after the `OR`. This will force the logic order and may fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. Your query is interpreted as follows:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM product
WHERE (status='A' AND subcat_id=5 AND product.price < 50) OR
      (product.price BETWEEN 50 AND 100 AND category = 'male')
```

You need to insert parentheses in the appropriate place to group the terms correctly. The only remaining question is precisely where to put them.

I think you mean this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM product
WHERE status='A'
AND subcat_id=5
AND (
    product.price < 50 OR 
    (product.price BETWEEN 50 AND 100 AND category = 'male')
)
```

This will show products under 50 for all categories, and products between 50 and 100 for the category male.

Answer (score 3):

You need a few more `()` to group your conditions.  If I understand correctly, you either want `product.price < 50` for any other match, or `product.price BETWEEN 50 AND 100` for males only. In that case, group those two conditions with `()`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  product
where 
  status='A' 
  and subcat_id=5
  AND (product.price < 50 OR  (product.price BETWEEN 50 AND 100 AND category = "male"))
```